# Regular expression doesn't act as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I use a regular expression to validate some form inputs with angularjs. I use the `ng-pattern` for that.

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^([A-z]){3}$/">
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="demoForm.$invalid">Ok</button>
```

If i type anything **not** matching the expression it is **not** valid (as expected). If i type what is matching the pattern it will be valid (as expected).

But it doesn't work as expected at all. If i type nothing (empty text input) the form is valid, and that is what i want to avoid: **It shouldn't be valid.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make the input `required`.

Comment: You `[A-z]` matches `_` and `]`.... Are you sure you want to match them? You do not say "exactly 3 *letters*" with `/^([A-z]){3}$/`. You also allow leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: That was already my idea, but i thought there must be something wrong with the pattern because i say i want EXACTLY 3 letters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the hint.

Comment: Try `<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[A-Z]{3}$/i" required ng-trim="false">`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give the input an `ng-model` attribute for Angular form validation to recognize it. You may also want to give the input a `name` attribute for more control. See [Angular Input documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

This example should demonstrate how `ng-model` and `name` can be used for form validation. Note that I've also adjusted your regex and made the input `required`.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  
  <form name="demoForm">
    
    <input type="text" 
           ng-model="myValue" 
           name="myInput" 
           ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/" 
           required />
    
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="demoForm.$invalid">Ok</button>
    
    <div>Input valid? {{demoForm.myInput.$valid}}</div>
    <div>Form valid? {{demoForm.$valid}}</div>
    <div>Model value: {{myValue}}</div>
  </form>
  
</div>
```